# Apache Camel: why is TCP connection not closed after receiving 200 OK

Tags: http, apache-camel

We are using Apache Camel as an orchestration engine. Typically, the following scenario:

client sends HTTP request <-> CAMEL code <-> external server(s)

The ball starts to roll when our client sends a HTTP request to our CAMEL code.
The Camel code will trigger external servers via REST HTTP calls.
Eventually, the Camel code will send a reply back to the client.

The last action before sending the response back to the client, the Camel code sends a HTTP GET towards an external server. So a TCP connection is setup first, then the data sent. After some time (this might take up 5 to 10 seconds), the external server replies with a 200 OK.

Problem: Camel does not send a TCP FIN to the external server after receiving the 200 OK. As a result, the TCP connection remains open ... (the external server then closes the TCP connection itself after a timeout of 200 seconds, but this means a TCP resource lost during 200 seconds).

So, at TCP level, it goes like this:

Camel <----------> external server

```
   TCP SYN  -->
   <-- TCP SYN,ACK
   TCP ACK  -->

   HTTP GET -->
   <-- 200 OK
   TCP ACK  -->

   <200 seconds later>
   <-- TCP FIN,ACK
   TCP ACK  -->
```

Any idea how I can have Camel close the TCP connection after it has received the 200 OK ?

Note: I tried adding the "Connection: close" header, but Camel did not add the header ?! It seemed to ignore it ...

This was the code to add the header:

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("Connection","Close");
```

I am using Camel 2.9.1 in a Spring framework with Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Which of Camels http component do you use?

Comment: Hi, I am using Camel 2.9.2 (not 2.9.1 as I mentioned earlier :() and camel-http-2.9.2.jar (and commons-httpclient-3.1.jar).

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with any HTTP server? Or the client's server is the only one that doesn't close the connection?

Comment: Hi Henryk, I expect the Camel code to close the TCP connection, not the external HTTP server (which now does it after 200 sec). In any case, I tried as external HTTP server: a Tomcat webserver and also a pure Jetty webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not see another solution than create a custom HttpHeaderFilterStrategy class which does not filter out the Connection header.
Then before sending out my request to the external server, I am setting the header "Connection: close". As soon as this request gets replied, the Camel code then sends a TCP FIN, ACK in order to close the TCP connection.

More details:

1) create a custom HttpHeaderFilterStrategy class, eg: CustomHttpHeaderFilterStrategy

2) adapt the applicationContext.xml so it points to that class, eg:

```
<bean id="http" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
    <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
    <property name="headerFilterStrategy" ref="myHeaderFilterStrategy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myHeaderFilterStrategy" class="com.alu.iptc.com.CustomHttpHeaderFilterStrategy">
</bean>
```

3) adapt your code, so that the Connection: close header is set, eg:

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("Connection","close");
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP1.1 connections are to be considered to be kept alive after the first message for a while to allow multiple files to be delivered in one TCP session for performance reasons. Normlly, a http server might cut connections after a few seconds to save threads while allow multiple files to be downloaded. The Camel http component will probably behave the same way.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

The official HTTP client which Camel relies on can be configured to use or not use persistent connections, but default is true:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html

Although I have not tried it, it should be possible to set a system property to configure this

```
http.keepAlive=<boolean>
```

You should be able to set it on the camel context if you want

```
<camelContext>
   <properties>
       <property key="http.keepAlive" value="false"/>
  </properties> 
</camelContext>
```

Note that I have not tried it. If you make it work, it would be nice to hear the results!

Comment: Too bad, tried it out but it did not seem to have any effect ... There should be a way to tell the Camel application that all required info has been received and hence the TCP connection can be closed, right ?

Comment: try setting it as a system property then. The HTTP4 client in Java should pick this up.

Comment: Could that be the difference: I am using the plain HTTP component and not the HTTP4 one ... ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to set it as a system property ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: java -Dhttp.keepAlive="false" MyCamelApplication

Comment: Grrr ... I can't get it to work ... Now, I did not try your last suggestion yet (as I am starting my Camel application through Spring/Eclise IDE and I am not sure where/how to add the -Dhttp.keepAlive parameter :() ... Something else what I do not understand: I set the header "Connection: close" and I also see that it is set in Camel when I print the headers to the console logging. Yet, when the message is sent out, it does NOT contain the Connection header ?! Could it be that Camel filters this header out before actually sending out the message ?

Comment: Sorry, That's pretty much all I know about the underlying implementation of the HTTP client.